# Finding column with closest date in R with dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lapply

I have a data frame with a list of subjects and a set of dates:

```
Subject    Date1       Date2       Date3      Date4      Date5     UniqueDate
001        12Mar02     03Apr02     08May02    09Jun02    22Jul02   02June02
002        15Feb05     03Mar05     18Apr05    01May05    16Jun05   22May05
...
100        22Jan09     01Feb09     28Mar09    10Apr09    21May09   29Jan09
```

I would like to find the last column name that the UniqueDate is greater than. So, for example, the result for `Subject 001` should be `Date3`.

I don't have a working solution yet, but this is what I am attempting to use for now:

```
colnames(DF[, 2:5])[apply(DF,1,which.max(DF[i] - DF$UniqueDate)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using basically the whole `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  nest(-Subject, -UniqueDate) %>% 
  mutate(latest_date = map2_chr(data, UniqueDate, ~ unlist(.x[max(which(dmy(.x) < dmy(.y)))])))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Subject UniqueDate data             latest_date
#>     <dbl> <chr>      <list>           <chr>      
#> 1       1 02June02   <tibble [1 x 5]> 08May02    
#> 2       2 22May05    <tibble [1 x 5]> 01May05    
#> 3     100 29Jan09    <tibble [1 x 5]> 22Jan09
```

The last line is a bit of a mess - hopefully you can see what's going on here.

Would be interested to see a base R solution to this.

#### Data

```r
df <-
  tribble(~Subject,    ~Date1,       ~Date2,       ~Date3,      ~Date4,      ~Date5,     ~UniqueDate,
          001,        "12Mar02",     "03Apr02",     "08May02",    "09Jun02",    "22Jul02",   "02June02",
          002,        "15Feb05",     "03Mar05",     "18Apr05",    "01May05",    "16Jun05",   "22May05",
          100,        "22Jan09",     "01Feb09",     "28Mar09",    "10Apr09",    "21May09",   "29Jan09")
```

Answer (score 0):

With your data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame("Subject" = c("001", "002", "003"),
                "Date1" = c("12Mar02", "15Feb05", "22Jan09"),
                "Date2" = c("03Apr02", "03Mar05", "01Feb09"),
                "Date3" = c("08May02", "18Apr05", "28Mar09"),
                "Date4" = c("09Jun02", "01May05", "10Apr09"),
                "Date5" = c("22Jul02", "16Jun05", "21May09"),
                "UniqueDate" = c("02June02", "22May05", "29Jan09"))
```

First you want to turn the date columns into a form R recognizes as dates:

```
d[, 2:7] <- lapply(d[, 2:7], as.Date, format = "%d%b%y")
```

Then store your desired results in a new column called `result` (note: this only works if the dates in Date1-Date4 are ranked from oldest to most recent:

```
d$result <- apply(d, 1, function(x){
  sum(x["UniqueDate"] > x[2:6])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution which uses a *rolling join* after reshaping the data to long format:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(DT), "Subject")[
  , value := lubridate::dmy(value)][]
long[variable != "UniqueDate"][long[variable == "UniqueDate"], 
                               on = .(Subject, value), .(Subject, variable), roll = Inf]
```

> ```
>    Subject variable
> 1:       1    Date3
> 2:       2    Date4
> 3:     100    Date1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
Subject    Date1       Date2       Date3      Date4      Date5     UniqueDate
001        12Mar02     03Apr02     08May02    09Jun02    22Jul02   02June02
002        15Feb05     03Mar05     18Apr05    01May05    16Jun05   22May05
100        22Jan09     01Feb09     28Mar09    10Apr09    21May09   29Jan09")
```